# An error with queue.get, bool object has no attribute get

Tags: python, multithreading, search, queue, match

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding=utf-8
import sys,os,threading
import Queue


keyword = sys.argv[1]
path = sys.argv[2]


class keywordMatch(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
    def run(self):
        while True:
            line = self.queue.get()
            if keyword in line:
                print line

            queue.task_done()
def main():
    concurrent = 100 # Number of threads
    queue = Queue.Queue()

    for i in range(concurrent):
        t = keywordMatch(True)
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start()

    allfiles = os.listdir(path)
    for files in allfiles:
        pathfile = os.path.join(path,files)
        fp = open(pathfile)
        lines = fp.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            queue.put(line.strip())
    queue.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This program is for searching the keyword in a directory, 
but there occurs an error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-100:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "du.py", line 17, in run
    line = self.queue.get()
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'get'
```

How can I get rid of the error?

Comment: `t = keywordMatch(True)`, did you mean `t = keywordMatch(queue)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're instantiating the thread with `t = keywordMatch(True)`, and then in `__init__` you're taking this argument and saving it as `self.queue` - so naturally `self.queue` is going to be a bool. If you want there to be a `Queue` instance there, you should pass it in.

Answer (score 1):

In `main()` you wrote:

```
t = keywordMatch(True)
```

The `keywordMatch` class's `__init__` does this:

```
def __init__(self,queue):
    self.queue = queue
```

So now `self.queue` is `True`! Later, trying to do `self.queue.get` fails because it isn't a queue at all.